# OpenGL: Texture loading but not applied

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut, soil

**UPDATE**

---

I've stopped using `glutSolidCube` and started applying the texture manually. Still no avail. Any ideas, if not, can you point me to an example in which a texture is successfully applied to a cube?

```
glRotatef(180, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texture);

glTranslatef(pos_x, 0, pos_z);

int size = 1;

// Begin Rending
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

// Face 1
glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( size, size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-size, size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-size, size, size);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f( size, size, size);    

// Face 2

glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( size,-size, size);    

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-size,-size, size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-size,-size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f( size,-size,-size);

// Face 3


glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( size, size, size);    

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-size, size, size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-size,-size, size);    

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f( size,-size, size);

// Face 4

glNormal3f( 0.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);  

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( size,-size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-size,-size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-size, size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f( size, size,-size);

// Face 5

glNormal3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-size, size, size);    

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f(-size, size,-size);    

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-size,-size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f(-size,-size, size);

// Face 6

glNormal3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( size, size,-size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
glVertex3f( size, size, size);

glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f( size,-size, size);

glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
glVertex3f( size,-size,-size);    

glEnd();
```

---

I'm making a simple voxel based game with OpenGL + Glut and I'm having trouble with loading a texture and applying it to a cube. The texture is created here:

```
texture = SOIL_load_OGL_cubemap (
    "block.png",
    "block.png",
    "block.png",
    "block.png",
    "block.png",
    "block.png",
    SOIL_LOAD_RGB,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS
);
```

And applied in the draw method here:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glutSolidCube(2);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); //enable texture coordinate generation
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
```

But when I run the application, I get a solid white cube still.

[image]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](http://i.snag.gy/ahxUt.jpg))</sub>

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: Did you `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)`?  Why are you using the `GL_TEXTURE_2D` target in `glBindTexture()` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`?

Comment: Tried that with both old and new solution, no luck.

Comment: Did you enable 2D textures? (glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)). Also, i'm not familiar with SOIL, but you probably should just be using 2D textures, not cube maps. Therefore, your call to SOIL_load_OGL_cubemap is probably incorrect. Look around to see if there is a SOIL function that will load a regular 2D texture.

Comment: @genpfault, why are cube map textures needed? Its my understanding that cube maping is used for reflections and stuff like that.

Comment: @redsoxfantom: No idea, OP was using `SOIL_load_OGL_cubemap()` so I figured they were trying to do cubemapping.

Comment: @DanPrince: For cube mapping, you will need 3D texture coordinates, and you need to `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP)`. Your "new" code doesn't use any of this.

Answer (score 0):

glutSolidCube does not include uv coordinates, therefore there is no way for OpenGL to know where the texture should be applied. I believe only glutSolidTeapot can be textured in this way? Not sure though.

Anyway, there isn't any way to easily texture glutSolidCube short of autogenerating uv coordinates. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, but this [link](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter09.html) might help. If you don't want to deal with autogenerating coordinates, than just manually draw your cubes and specify uvs there.